# Dependency injection . Same type , different instances for multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I would like to have two instances, differ in a property (which for I created am extensions WithB /WithC , setting this property)
I would like to register them as scoped services
so I become with this solution

```
public interface IInterfaceA { }

public interface IInterfaceB : IInterfaceA { }

public interface IInterfaceC : IInterfaceA { }

internal class A : IInterfaceB, IInterfaceC 
{   
   public A(){} 
}
```

and injecting it like this

```
    services.AddTransient<IInterfaceA, A>();

    services.AddScoped<IInterfaceB>((serviceProvider) =>
    {
        IInterfaceA B = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IInterfaceA>()
        .WithB();

        return B as IInterfaceB;
    });

    services.AddScoped<IInterfaceC>((serviceProvider) =>
    {
        IInterfaceC C = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IInterfaceA>()
        .WithC();

        return C as IInterfaceC;
    });
```

If I am not wrong the a different A instance will be created for each IInterfaceB/IInterfaceC and its lifetime will be scoped.

Is that correct ?
Any other best practices for this situation (assuming I do not want to two classed derived from A class ?

Comment: What is `WithB` and `WithC`? Could you not just register `A` as the implementation type for `IInterfaceB` and `IInterfaceC`?

Comment: "_If I am not wrong the a different A instance will be created for each IInterfaceB/IInterfaceC and its lifetime will be scoped_" This is correct.

Comment: Feels like the [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need a separate instances of A. one which set tye parameter using WithA and one which set it using WithB extension

Comment: WithA and WithB can be ofncourse the same method wity different parameter